# Call https asmx web service from PHP with multiple parameters wordpress blog

Tags: php, wordpress, web-services, https

I am trying to call  a HTTPS ASMX service from my PHP blog

Here is my code

```css
$param1="Web Submission";
$param2="Lead";
$param3="flase";
$param0=$comment_content;
if (!empty($comment_content)){
$client = new SoapClient("https://devop.setars.com/webservice/sellblog.asmx?wsdl");
$params->Notes=$param0;
$params->Type=$param1;
$params->PURPOSE=$param2;
$params->IsMail=$param3;
$result=$client->AddActivity($params);
}
```

When I tested this locally with HTTP it is working fine, but when hosting with HTTPS, it doesn't appear to be making the call correctly.

```css
    $param1="Web Submission";
$param2="Lead";
$param3="flase";
$param0=$comment_content;
if (!empty($param0)){
$client = new SoapClient("http://localhost:52078/WebService/SellBlog.asmx?wsdl");
$params->Notes=$param0;
$params->Type=$param1;
$params->PURPOSE=$param2;
$params->IsMail=$param3;
$result=$client->AddActivity($params);
}
```

I tried with this also but no solution

```css
$soap_options = array(
        'trace'       => 1, 
        'exceptions'  => 1 ,
      );
$wsdl = "https://dev234.sentsis.com/webservice/sellblog.asmx?WSDL";

$param1="Web Submission";
$param2="Lead";
$param3="flase";
$param0=$comment_content;
if (!empty($comment_content)){
$client = new SoapClient( $wsdl, $soap_options);
$params->Notes=$param0;
$params->Type=$param1;
$params->PURPOSE=$param2;
$params->IsMail=$param3;
$result=$client->AddActivity($params)->AddActivityResult;
}
```

Is there any difference between making a service call from PHP to a HTTP service compared to a HTTPS one?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect to a server that only supports SSLv2/3 and/or TLS 1.0 (no TLS 2 or 3), tell the SOAP client if you get a connection error by setting the appropriate stream context, example:

```
<?php
  $opts = array(
    'ssl' => array('ciphers'=>'RC4-SHA')
  );

  $client = new SoapClient(
    'https://example.com/?wsdl',
    array ( "encoding"=>"ISO-8859-1",
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create($opts)
    // your options
    );
?>
```

You might need to disable the SOAP caching of WSDLs in order for the SOAP client to use the new context.